# Run-time error 1004 cannot open pivottable source file

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm new at VBA and Macros. Following Macro Recording, I ended up with this bug.

The file name is available on desktop with the correct name.

Thanks for any help,

```
Sub Macro2435Pivot()
'
' Macro2435Pivot Macro
'

'
    Cells.Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "2435_Monthly Sales with Adjustm'!1:15000", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!R3C1", TableName:= _
        "PivotTable" & [=round(Rand()*1000,0)], DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Month")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
```

Comment: Which lines returns the error.  Can you include the error message?  They're more descriptive than the code.

Comment: Remove the `.Select` calls, they're just macro-recorder junk that mimick cell clicks. VBA code doesn't need them. Work with `Worksheets("Sheet2")` instead of `ActiveSheet`, and you won't need to `.Select` or `.Activate` anything. @destination-data error 1004 is "application-defined error", which isn't helpful at all. Knowing whether it's the `PivotCaches.Create` or the `PivotTable.PivotFields` member call that's failing would be useful though.

Comment: Thanks, Mat, Actually I re-worked on the file again but I now have a different issue.

Comment: run-time error '9' Script out of range with Colored line below:        Windows("Testing file with Macro.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of Profit"), "Sum of Profit", xlSum
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 26.71
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 17
    Windows("Macro 2435.xlsx").Activate
    Windows("Testing file with Macro.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField